# Get webkit version in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, webkit

I'm working on OSX application that needs a CSS preview. 
I need to find a way to differentiate users with safari 5.0 from users with safari 5.1 because webkit preview has many differences in this 2 versions. 
For example, the gradient radial interpretation is totally different!

Is there a way to intercept the webkit version ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the user-agent string for the current WebKit version using JavaScript. Just do something like this:

```
NSString* userAgent = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
```

which will produce something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.51.14 (KHTML, like Gecko)
```

You can then parse the user-agent string to get the version of WebKit in use.

Answer (score 5):

This helps you getting the WebKit version **before** loading the request so you could probably put together your own user agent. So this solution is better:

```
NSBundle *webKit = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.WebKit"];
NSString *version = [[webKit infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

if (webKit && [webKit load]) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [webKit infoDictionary]);
}

[webKit unload]; // you might also unload the bundle, if you don't need it later
```

Comment: First answer (`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`) didn't work, returned null for some reason, but this one did.

Comment: This could happen when the WebView is not fully loaded and JS is not completely initialized. Try the same JS in the web inspector to check if it is a general issie or a timing problem (when ever you might work with JS/WebKit again)

Comment: I thought of that and waited 5 seconds - still no deal.

Comment: Hmm. Sad :/ But great I could help!

Comment: Actually, I finally did get `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to work. Seems like something else was wrong.  

Just to be clear, your code worked right away.  

For anyone looking to map AppleWebKit version numbers to versions of Safari, [http://www.browserscope.org/](http://www.browserscope.org/browse?category=acid3&ua=Safari%208.0) is useful.

Comment: Interesting link, thanks for sharing. Even though one can possibly force Safari for a specific WebKit version, so you can use for example the latest nighly build (I did this in the past). What caused your issie in the end?